# No extra mouse buttons in 12.10 vmware guest

Tags: mouse, vmware

Windows Vmware Workstation 9 host. No extra mouse buttons in 12.10 guest as verified with xev. This is working in 12.04. Neither setup use xorg.conf. No special setup needed to get extra mouse buttons working in 12.04 guest.

Any ideas on how to get extra mouse buttons in 12.10 vmware guest?

Comment: Did you ever solve this?

Answer (score 1):

Previously answered by http://ubuntuforums.org/archive/index.php/t-1347424.html

Turns out to be a Vmware thing. vmx needed the following line:
mouse.vusb.enable = "TRUE"

Comment: Thanks, but not there yet, unfortunately :-(

Comment: I assume the `.vmx` file should be placed in my home directory on the Ubuntu guest system.

Comment: It may work for someone else, so +1.