# Disable auto repeat mouse wheel left/right button of logitech mouse

Tags: mouse, logitech, mouse-wheel

I used [How to assign "back" and "forward" actions to Logitech Anywhere Mouse MX' horizontal scroll wheel?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/101105/how-to-assign-back-and-forward-actions-to-logitech-anywhere-mouse-mx-horizo) to link my logitech mouse buttons. It works well, except for the mouse wheel left and right buttons.
I would like them to do copy and paste. So I tried this code (in `.xbindkeysrc`):

```
#copy
"xdotool key ctrl+c"
b:6

#paste
"xdotool key ctrl+v"
b:7
```

It works fine, but pressing a button act with auto repeat, so I get multiples pastes.
I would like to disable the auto repeat for those two buttons, but the only method I know is with `xset`, but it only recognizes keycode, and I think that my tow button don't have keycode.
How can I do this?